# Bigraded endomorphisms of the motivic sphere over a field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, stable-homotopy, motivic-homotopy, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

In *An introduction to $\mathbb A^1$-homotopy theory* ([1]) and *On the motivic $\pi_0$ of the sphere spectrum* ([2]) Morel describes a computation of $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb Z} [S^0, \mathbb G_m^{\wedge n}]$, where the brackets mean "homotopy classes of maps in $\mathbb P^1$-spectra over a perfect field $k$".

In [2] there isn't much more to that statement than that, but in [1] he gives the slightly more general motivation of trying to compute $[S^i,\mathbb G_m^{\wedge n}]$ for arbitrary $i,n$. Of course, he mentions that for $i<0$ this is simply $0$, and the theorem he describes is the $i=0$ case. But there seems to be no mention of the $i>0$ case.

One "obvious" reason for that to be complicated is that for $i>0$ and $n=0$, that would presumably be related to computing the stable homotopy groups of spheres (e.g. if $k$ can be embedded in $\mathbb R$, then I think that the classical stable homotopy groups of $S^0$ split off the ones in $\mathbb P^1$-spectra) - which is not a problem in the $i=0$ case (or $i\leq 0$ more generally).

But can we imagine a computation of these groups *in terms of* the classical stable homotopy groups of spheres ? We have a morphism from the graded ring $\pi_*(S^0)$ to the bigraded ring $\pi_{*,*}^{\mathbb P^1}(S^0)$ given by the (unique) symmetric monoidal colimit preserving functor $\mathbf{Sp}\to \mathcal{SH}^{\mathbb P^1}(k)$, so we can definitely view the latter as an algebra or a module over the former :

> Is there a way to describe this algebra/module structure "explicitly" ?

By "explicitly" I mean a description similar to Morel's description of the $i=0$ case, where we have an expression in terms of Milnor-Witt groups.  Speaking of which, I happen to have a reference question about the same thing, so if it's appropriate, I'll just ask it here too :

> Are there other references than [1] and [2] where the computation of $[S^0,\mathbb G_m^{\wedge n}]$ is explained ? Ideally, more "expository" references.

Comment: $\pi_{1,0}\mathbb{1}$ (I always get confused by motivic grading) is computed in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.00365.pdf. For an expository article, perhaps:

Østvær, Paul Arne (2020). Motivic stable homotopy groups, In Haynes Miller (ed.),  Handbook of Homotopy Theory.  Chapman & Hall/CRC.  ISBN 9780815369707.  Motivic stable homotopy groups.  s 759 - 793

Comment: OK, the latter is the same as https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.05729.pdf, and is also coauthored by Isaksen.

Comment: @DrewHeard Thank you ! So it seems like the answer to the first question is that there's not an obvious description in terms of $\pi_*(S^0)$. And the expository paper looks nice, but I don't think it actually contains that specific computation, unless i'm mistaken